# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory (Needed 4194092 bytes)

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I'm receiving the following error on my shared hosting box:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory (Needed 4194092 bytes)

This error is only triggered on a specific page.

I guess this indicates that I am reaching the upper limit of the 64MB allocated to me in my current MySQL environment.

Does this mean that a **single query** is going over (returning) 64MB of data? If so, i guess i can just track down and tune that specific query? Or isnt that the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Appears it failed to allocate about `4 MB` of data during the query. You may be able to see this in the log output, such as with `slow_queries`. It's most likely a `SELECT` query, you may be able to find it by doing this in a near parent directory:

```
grep "SELECT" `find | grep "php$"`
```